Extruder digging into filament Ender 3 V2 Neo
I am a newbie in 3D printing. I bought a used Ender 3 V2 Neo from a shop (demo unit/display model) few days ago and I have been trying it in few hours sessions. A problem I came across twice now in the middle of printing is nothing gets extruded out.
I paused the printing and checked the filament. It seems that the extruder was digging too deep into the filament that it cannot be pushed/pulled anymore. Checking the mark further down seems to suggest that it was fine because the digging mark wasn't too deep up until the halt.
I also noticed that the top layers where some filament still get extruded have pretty bad extrusion quality. Something like getting thinner the longer it print, until nothing gets extruded I assume. Most of the layers were printed nicely without much issue. I am using the material provided inside the box when I bought it, which I assume is PLA.
How and why does this happen and how do I prevent or fix it?

Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please add photos to show what the problem is. It could be heat creep, but I think there are possibly more problems.
